# Can an I2S speaker and microphone share the same I2S clock? What about word select?

Tags: gpio, pins, i2s, sharedbus

If one is very tight on GPIOs, could an I2S TX and RX share any pins?

Edit: The device I was thinking of was the ESP32, connected to an I2S microphone and speaker, for example SPH0645 and MAX98357A.

Comment: Does this answer your question : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%C2%B2S

Comment: And then ther's this : https://web.archive.org/web/20070102004400/http://www.nxp.com/acrobat_download/various/I2SBUS.pdf

Comment: It depends. We can't possibly know what features are possible with your chips, because you are not telling which chips they are.

Comment: @Justme apologies I thought the chipset may not matter. I've edited the question.