# Raspberry Pi I2S speaker and microphones on the same connection

Tags: raspberry-pi, speakers, microphone, i2s

I am planning on buying an I2S speaker amplifier for my Raspberry Pi project. I already have the microphones for it. My question is whether the I2S interface can support speaker and mic at the same time.

The answer found [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/537836/can-an-i2s-speaker-and-microphone-share-the-same-i2s-clock-what-about-word-sele) does not actually have an answer, and reading the I2S spec is not helping either.

If it matters, I am using the [Adafruit I2S MEMS Microphone Breakout - SPH0645LM4H](https://www.adafruit.com/product/3421) and I am planning on using the [Adafruit I2S 3W Class D Amplifier Breakout - MAX98357A](https://www.adafruit.com/product/3006)

Note: I want the mics to feed into the Pi, and the speaker to have the audio from the Pi, not the mic to the speaker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Adafruit https://forums.adafruit.com/viewtopic.php?p=955929#p955929

> You can have:
>
> - Multiple speakers on both the left and right channels
> - One mic on the left channel and multiple speakers on the right channel
> - Multiple speakers on the left channel and one mic on the right channel
> - One mic on the left channel and one mic on the right channel
>
> You can't have more than two mics (one on each channel) and if you do have two mics you can't have speakers (both channels are already in use by the mics).

Therefore, I will need to find another way to get sound out of the raspberry pi